# x86 Assembly: Programming Insertion_sort as a beginner

Tags: sorting, assembly, x86

I have been very much annoyed to complete this .asm code.
This result must be printed in order by using Insertion_Sort.

I actually tried Bubble_Sort in case the logic of Algorithm might be wrong. I would like to ask you to read through this code. Any advice would be very welcome. I really want to know what I missed.

Here is the result I got so far: ( the rlt of Bubble sort is also very strange. Since I don't know how to debug in asm, I can't help just reading through the code again and again. Desperate in help. )

> 1 3 5 2 7 4 6 8 9 10

```
 %include "asm_io.inc"
 section .data
   array dd 3,1,5,7,2,8,4,9,6,10
   size dd 10
   segment .bss
   next resw 1
 segment .text
 global main
 main:
   enter 0,0
   pusha
   ; Insertion Sort Start from here 
   mov eax,[array+4*ecx]
   mov [next], eax
   ; j = i-1
   mov ebx, ecx
   dec ebx
 while2:
   cmp ebx,0
   jl EndLoop2
   mov eax, [next]
   cmp [array+4*ebx],eax
   jle EndLoop2
   ;array[j+1] = array[j]
   mov eax, [array+4*ebx]
   mov [array+4*(ebx+1)], eax
   ; j--
   dec ebx
   ; Go back to the top of this loop
   jp while2
 EndLoop2:
   mov eax, [next]
   mov [array+4*(ebx+1)],eax
   inc ecx
   jmp while1
 EndLoop1:
   mov ecx,0
 nextInt:
   mov eax, [array+4*ecx]
   call print_int
   call print_nl
   inc ecx
   cmp [size], ecx
   jne nextInt
   popa
   mov eax, 0
   leave
   ret
```

Comment: You should learn how to debug in asm. It should be even easier than debugging high level languages, because each asm instruction does only one thing. (When you do, you'll probably notice something funny at the `jp`.)

Comment: Get yourself a debugger! There are many available. It is much easier to understand what the program does when you can watch it as it executes step by step. I note that you forgot to ask a question. What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

Errors include:

- You use the `ECX` register in `mov eax,[array+4*ecx]` but fail to set it up beforehand.
- With `mov [next], eax` you write a **dword** in a variable that was defined as a **word**.
- Where does this `jmp while1` go? There's no such label!
- Not sure if the assembler can understand this addressing: `mov [array+4*(ebx+1)], eax`. Perhaps change it to: `mov [array+4*ebx+4], eax`
- `jp while2` Shouldn't this be a mere `jmp`? There are no parities to be checked here.

First solve all of these...

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea, why I logged in another account and questioned, the above one(user3787105) is me, I just want to say that I solved the problem. and the errors made me crazy was caused by unnecessarily used "DEC" and "INC".
thanks, guys. and sorry for not giving you any advantage for the reason I forgot the password on user3787105 account.